# Javascript possible for "this" reference in nested dictionary?

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome

I am doing some simple vanilla js scripting. When doing this i often use dictionaries instead of classes for since it works across most browsers.

I noticed altough, when creating a new dict aka `var navtabs = {}`. Inside of that dict i can now reference `this` which refers to the active dict aka `navtabs`, which is awesome. However im confused as when i place a nested dict (`file` in my minimal code below) and reference this inside that nested dict, `this` still reference to the topmost `navtabs` variable.

am i doing something wrong simply, or is there another "hackish" solution to create some sort of "this" variable inside nested dicts to avoid specifying navtabs.file.randomMethod?

```
var navtabs = {
    activeTab: undefined,
    onNewTabLoad: ,
    getCurrentTab:,
    add_all_tab_events: ,
    file: {
        id: dom_navbar_tab_file.id,
        onLoad: function () {},
        currentFiles: [],
        currentFiles_OnChange: [],
        addCurrentFiles: function(file){
            this.file.currentFiles.push(file);
            this.file.currentFiles_OnChange.forEach(callback => {
                callback(currentFiles);
            });
        }
    },
```

Comment: The value of `this` inside `addCurrentFiles` is determined by how you call `addCurrentFiles`. While there are ways to make it reference the object assigned to `navtabs`, they aren't ways you would typically call the function so I don't know why you get that result. You should provide a [mcve].

Comment: "*Inside of that dict i can now reference `this` which refers to the active dict*" - no, that's not [how the `this` keyword works](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this).